# Does lava set signs on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was trying to make a mob farm, but I made it too short. I remembered that you can use lava to burn the mobs, and I thought about a way for the mobs to go through a block but the lava wouldn't (so the drops don't burn). Then I thought of signs, but now I'm worried that the sign will burn because it's made from wood.

Does lava set signs on fire, or can I safely do this?

[image: lava over sign]

Comment: It won't. I use signs to hold lava in place. Haven't had them burn up yet.

Comment: Regardless of whether signs are flammable, in your particular case there seems to be no space to spawn a fire block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes or no, depending what version you are on.

In minecraft PE signs will burn, in all other versions it will not burn.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire#Burning_blocks

Comment: It looks like it does burn in PE. That makes me wonder if it burns in the Windows 10 beta version since it is compatible with PE in regards to multiplayer. That leads me to also wonder if future releases of the main computer version will switch to burn able signs. Something to look out for on the change logs for future releases.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell yeah i should look out for it

Comment: @ModDL  you  are right

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell and you are right

Comment: and btw im on PC

Comment: Noooo! I was about to do the same thing with the signs!

Comment: wow it doesent work in PE version